# How to highlight something?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Should I highlight using `backticks` or **bold font**?

I want to highlight "Settings" and "keyboard" in this text:

> Go to Settings and select keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment to [one of your posts](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/4044/1401), backticks (`` ` ``) are for highlighting code samples, console commands and such, similar to the four-space indentation. The only difference is that backticks are meant for inline formatting, whereas four-space indent applies to multiple lines.

Backticks should *not* be used for general-purpose highlighting of things like menu options, names of apps, and so on. For such things, use **bold** or *italics*. For multi-word menu items or options, enclosing them in "quotation marks" is also a good option.

This use of backticks is long-standing policy on Stack Exchange, based on the [official Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) (Markdown is the syntax you're using to format your posts on SE sites). For more information, see [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990)